# How to append CSV file Data with null value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new in python and pandas dataset framework. I am trying to union or append two csv file Data. In first step I am able to read CSV file but later desired output is not coming. my CSV file contains below data

*physical.csv*

```
title,stage,jan,feb
darn,3.001,0.421,0.532
ok,2.829,1.036,0.751
three,1.115,1.146,2.921
```

*digital.csv*

```
title,mar,apr,may,jun,
darn,0.631,1.321,0.951,1.751
ok,1.001,0.247,2.456,0.3216
three,0.285,1.283,0.924,956
```

**Expected output:**

```
darn  3.001  0.421  0.532  darn null null null null
ok  2.829  1.036  0.751  ok null null null null
three  1.115  1.146  2.921  three null null null null
darn null null null darn,0.631,1.321,0.951,1.751 
ok null null null ok,1.001,0.247,2.456,0.3216
three null null null three,0.285,1.283,0.924,956
```

**My Python code is:**

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("D:/BMG/physical.csv")
physicalColumn = a.columns        
print("physical.csv : ", a)

b = pd.read_csv("D:/BMG/digital.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
digitalColumn = b.columns
print("digital.csv : ", b)

appendColumns = physicalColumn.append(digitalColumn)
print("appendColumns : ", appendColumns)

merged = a.append(b)
m_col = ['title','stage','jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun']
merged.columns = m_col
print("merge data : ", merged)
```

Output that I'm getting from my code:

```
('merge data : ',    title  stage    jan       feb    mar    apr    may    jun
 0    NaN  0.532  0.421       NaN    NaN    NaN  3.001   darn
 1    NaN  0.751  1.036       NaN    NaN    NaN  2.829     ok
 2    NaN  2.921  1.146       NaN    NaN    NaN  1.115  three
 0  1.321    NaN    NaN    1.7510  0.631  0.951    NaN   darn
 1  0.247    NaN    NaN    0.3216  1.001  2.456    NaN     ok
 2  1.283    NaN    NaN  956.0000  0.285  0.924    NaN  three)
```

Comment: `merged[appendColumns]`?

Answer (score 1):

- [concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) function does all of the heavy lifting of performing concatenation operations along an axis while performing optional set logic (union or intersection) of the indexes (if any) on the other axes.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


str1 = StringIO('''title,stage,jan,feb
darn,3.001,0.421,0.532
ok,2.829,1.036,0.751
three,1.115,1.146,2.921''')

a = pd.read_csv(str1,sep=',')
print("---a----")
print(a)

str2 = StringIO('''title,mar,apr,may,jun,
darn,0.631,1.321,0.951,1.751
ok,1.001,0.247,2.456,0.3216
three,0.285,1.283,0.924,956
''')

b = pd.read_csv(str2,sep=',')
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
print("---b---")
print(b)

print("-----output-------")
bigdata = pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True, sort =False)
print(bigdata)
```

**O/P:**

**---a----**

```
   title  stage    jan    feb
0   darn  3.001  0.421  0.532
1     ok  2.829  1.036  0.751
2  three  1.115  1.146  2.921
```

**---b---**

```
   title    mar    apr    may       jun
0   darn  0.631  1.321  0.951    1.7510
1     ok  1.001  0.247  2.456    0.3216
2  three  0.285  1.283  0.924  956.0000
```

**-----output-------**

```
   title  stage    jan    feb    mar    apr    may       jun
0   darn  3.001  0.421  0.532    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
1     ok  2.829  1.036  0.751    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
2  three  1.115  1.146  2.921    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
3   darn    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.631  1.321  0.951    1.7510
4     ok    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.001  0.247  2.456    0.3216
5  three    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.285  1.283  0.924  956.0000
```

Comment: IIUC, the OP wants two columns named `title` as well.